# Proof that subset A of $\mathbb{R}$ is not open

Tags: general-topology

I'm self-studying an introductory book on topology and came across this exercise:

> Prove that the following subset $A=$ {$x \in \mathbb{R}: x \neq 1/n, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} of $\mathbb{R}$ is not open.

My intuition is that $z \notin A$ where $z = 0+1/n$ as $n \to \infty$. (What I mean by this is that the next real number arbitrarily close to $0$ on the real line is not in $A$. I don't know if it's written correctly.) Then $\not\exists r>0$ such that $(0-r, 0+r) \subset A$.

Is my intuition correct? If so, how do I make this into a correct (but preferably still intuitive) proof?

Comment: You have basically a complete proof.  Note that $0\in A$. We will show that there is no open interval $(-r,r)$ such that $(-r,r)\subset A$.  Let interval $(-r,r)$ be given. There is a positive integer $n$ such that $n\gt 1/r$. But then $0\lt \frac{1}{n}\lt r$, but the point $\frac{1}{n}$ is not in $A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you! This is what I was looking for. Would you make that an answer?

Comment: Well, you had given a pretty full answer, I did only confirmed it and suggested a way of wording it. So it is really you that should be answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my question had all that was needed to prove the statement, so as as suggested by André I'll answer the question myself. I'll use his version of the proof as this is what I was looking for when I asked here.

> Prove that the following subset $A=$ {$x \in \mathbb{R}: x \neq 1/n, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} of $\mathbb{R}$ is not open.

Note that $0 \in A$. We show that there is no open interval $(−r,r)$ such that $(−r,r) \subset A$.

Let interval $(−r,r)$ be given. There is a positive integer $n$ such that $n>\frac{1}{r}$. But then $0<\frac{1}{n}<r$ and the point $\frac{1}{n}$ is in the interval $(-r, r)$ but not in $A$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your method is correct. It's important to specify which topology you're working with though. If $\mathbb{R}$ is given the standard topology, then its basis open sets will be of the form $B_{\epsilon}(x) = (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $\epsilon>0$. So since $0\in A$ and since there is no basis open set $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ with $0\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq A$, $A$ cannot be open.

Alternatively, you could show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is not closed (a set is open iff its complement is closed). You could do this by noting that $0\in \overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}$, but $0\not\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$.